# Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received an object

Tags: arrays, angularjs-filter, angularjs-rootscope

Hi I am trying to create a basic global search which will filter results on the pages depending on which view (controller) is present.

Search controller:

```
    <form ng-controller="searchCtrl">
      <div class="container col-md-12">
        <div class="row margin col-md-2">
        <label>Search</label>
        <input ng-model="searchSite" type="text" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      </div>
  </form>
```

View controller example:

```
 .state('Blog', {
    url: '/blog',
    controller: 'BlogCtrl as blg',
    templateUrl: 'blog.html',
    title: 'Blog'
  })
```

Blog controller:

```
controllersModule.controller('BlogCtrl', ["$scope", "postsDB", function($scope, postsDB) {



//postsDB is the factory pulling the API
        postsDB.query(function(posts){
             $scope.myPosts = posts;
         })
}]);
```

THE HTML OUTPUT

```
       <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
         <img class="activator" src="images/sample-1.jpg">
       </div>
       <div class="card-content">
         <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">{{post.Title}}<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
         <p><a href="#">Read More</a></p>
         <p>By: {{post.Author}} &nbsp; Published on: {{post.Published | date:'mediumDate'}}</p>
       </div>
       <div class="card-reveal">
         <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">{{post.Title}}<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
         <div>{{post.Intro}}</div>
         <p ng-bind-html="post.Body">{{post.Body}}</p>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962865/global-search-box-in-angular) as a reference and setting the "searchSite" query as a global object with `$rootScope`:

```
controllersModule.controller( 'searchCtrl','$scope', '$rootScope','$firebaseArray',function($scope, $rootScope, $firebaseArray) {

    $rootScope.searchSite = $firebaseArray('');
});
```

The reason to turn this into an array is because I am getting the error `Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array` but even after changing it, I am still getting the same error.